# How to refresh UIWebView images

Tags: ios, swift, caching, uiwebview

I went through a few SO post and can't seem to fix my issues.

The codes works fine, but if i update my profile pics, the UIWebView, will still show the cached image instead of the updated image.

if i close my app and reopen, the webview will update to the new image.

any pointer are greatly appreciated.

```
func getLeaderBoard()
    {
        leaderWebView.loadRequest(getStaticWebView(urlStr: getLeaderBoardUrl) as URLRequest)
    }  

 func getStaticWebView(urlStr:String) -> NSMutableURLRequest
    {

        let url = URL.init(string: urlStr)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest.init(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("token \(kToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData

        URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
        URLCache.shared.diskCapacity = 0
        URLCache.shared.memoryCapacity = 0

        return request
    }
```

Comment: Is your cache/cookies has been cleared?

Comment: Can you tell me, does the page actually load when refreshing? More specially, are you saying the images are persisting between one instance of the web view to another? (i.e. go away and come back but keep app ope)

Comment: did you try webView.reload() ? in your case it should leaderWebView.reload()

Comment: @Niroj yea, i believe so

Comment: @MitchellCurrie yes

Comment: @UdayaSri yea, i'm not sure if is because my server is slower

Comment: Couple of things you can try... like adding a random param string on the end to fool it as a different url, or try destroying the web view and loading it again. Also could be cache time on the images from the server in the header